# Remove OPTIONS request between domain and subdomain?

Tags: cors, cross-domain

We need to structure our website so that the frontend and backend run on different machine and the frontend will be making ajax request to the backend to get data to render.

The challenge we are facing is that by that design the browser which render the frontend need to submit OPTIONS request anytime it contact the backend.

Is there a way around?
For example we run the frontend at `service.com`, and the backend at `api.service.com`, it makes sense that `service.com` should be able to access to "X.Y.Z.service.com" without a need for constant OPTIONS preflight request, shouldn't it?

Comment: For cross-origin requests, browsers only make a CORS preflight OPTIONS request under certain conditions. For the the list of conditions, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests. So if you want browsers to not need to do the preflight OPTIONS, you need to change whatever characteristic of the requests your frontend JavaScript code is making, such that the requests do not trigger a preflight. For example, if you’re using an Authorization header to do authentication, you can switch to doing authentication using a query parameter in the URL.

Comment: Look like it the way now. A bit confused that header is preflight but any params is ok.

Comment: The reason params don’t cause a preflight: the CORS protocol was designed to allow any cross-origin requests from script you could always make using HTML elements like `<img href>` with a cross-origin URL, or `<link href>` or `<script src>` with a cross-origin URL. So in those HTML-element-with-cross-origin-URL cases, you can have any query params you want in the URL & the browser will allow it cross-origin—*but* there ’s no way you can add headers to the request the browser makes in the HTML-element cases. Therefore, adding headers to *scripted* cross-origin requests is disallowed by default

Comment: …but the CORS protocol lets servers to opt-in to allowing that behavior that’s disallowed by default—that is, the CORS protocol lets a server indicate it allows scripted cross-origin that include particular request headers. And the response the server makes to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request is the way the CORS protocol provides for servers to tell browsers that the server is opting-in to more liberal behavior than the strict default behavior of disallowing all cross-origin requests that have headers added

Answer (score 0):

You can annex the options callfrom happening by setting the header: `Access-Control-Max-Age:<seconds>`. However the browser will still have to make the 1st options call. The header tells how long to avoid the subsequent options call.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age